# SQL SUM then count?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sum

Table Historical_Inventory

Column: Date, Prod_ID, WHStock, Stock_Allocated

I want to count the amount of times a products (WHstock - stock allocated) <= 0 between date x and y where Prod_ID = "id1"

Any ideas?

I was going along the lines of

```
SELECT Count `Prod_ID`
     , sum((`WHStock`-`Stock_Allocated`)) as Stock 
  from Historic_Inventory 
 WHERE `Date` Between '2018-04-01'and '2018-08-01'
   AND Stock <= 0
```

But not working very well..

Comment: `not working very well` what does that mean? What output you are getting? Can you share the sample data and the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM
(SELECT SUM((`WHStock`-`Stock_Allocated`)) AS Stock 
FROM Historic_Inventory 
WHERE `Date` Between '2018-04-01'and '2018-08-01') AS t
WHERE t.Stock <= 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT Prod_ID, SUM(WHStock - Stock_Allocated) as Stock 
      FROM Historic_Inventory 
      WHERE `Date` Between '2018-04-01' and '2018-08-01'
      GROUP BY Prod_ID
     ) x
WHERE Stock <= 0;
```

Hmmm. . . this counts the number of *products* where the value is negative.

Perhaps you want:

```
select hi.*
       (@stock := @stock + (WHStock - Stock_Allocated)) as stock
from (select hi.*
      from historic_inventory hi
      where prod_id = ?
      order by date
     ) hi cross join
     (select @stock := 0) params
having stock < 0;
```